# javascript: find the name of an array key for use in an if..then loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

i'm iterating through and associative array like so:

```
for (entry in $data[array]) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

i need to assign a value based on the NAME of a key, like so (pseudo-code):

```
for (entry in $data[array]) {
  // do some stuff
  if ($data[array][entry]['type'].name = 'thingy') {
    // so some other stuff
  } else {
    // keep doing some stuff
  }
}
```

thing is, i can't get the zero'th element to cough up its key name such that it can be used as i've typed it (i'm aware it doesn't work...) the array itself looks like this:

```
$data
(
    [success] => 1
    [findings] =>
        (
            [0] =>
                (
                    [type] => thingy
                    [name] => yo-yo
                    [age] => 1960    
                )
            [1] =>
                (
                    [type] => doohickey
                    [name] => clothespin
                    [age] => 1940    
                )
        )
)
```

so...essentially what i'm needing to do is do something different if the KEY is a 'type'. basically for every key of 'type', make text red, for example.

what am i missing to make it work?  :P  i hope i'm making myself clear...

WR!

Comment: I find your pseudo-code very confusing. Is the idea that `array` will be a string variable, with its value being `'success'` or `'findings'`? And, what do you mean by "the KEY" or "the NAME of a key"? It seems like the "name" or "key" of `$data[array][entry]['type']` is simply `'type'`. No? I think that *real* code, with actual JavaScript syntax, would probably be more clear.

Comment: Your whole presentation is confused on various accounts. For starters, there's no `then` in JS. Next, an `if` is a conditional, not a loop. Sloppiness leads you straight into bugland. Then, you're assigning in a conditional - likely a bug. Also `age` as 1940 and 1960, that's probably year of birth. - What are you trying to say anyway?

Comment: OMG, *seriously*?  please tell me you're joking... this is actual working JS with a simple array pulled from a CSV file! the only 'pseudo' part is the `.name` i tacked on the end to indicate i was looking for the key's name there.  for the tarde-mente: `if (the keys name is 'thingy) {do other stuff} else {do stuff}.

Comment: @WhiteRau: To clarify, the things I found confusing were (1) the pseudo-code (non-JavaScript) object notation; (2) the fact that said object notation, taken literally, seemed to be trying to use arrays as keys; (3) the fact that your initial code used `array` as a variable-name to refer to a key, reinforcing this notion; and (4) the fact that your whole question was asking how to do something -- pardon me -- something incredibly obvious, so I assumed that I must be misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first value in the `for (key in set)` syntax is, in fact, the key.

```
for (entry in $data[array]) {
  // do some stuff
  for (thing in $data[array][entry]) {
    if (thing === 'type') {
      //do stuff
    } else {
      // do other stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think i tried a flavour of that, but must have fudged it somehow because it wasn't working, so i abandoned it.  seeing it now, i know where i went wrong.  your way much clearer.  thank you very much.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well then you should try following:

```
for (entry in $data[array]) {
    // do some stuff
    if ($data[array][entry]['type'] = 'thingy') {
        // so some other stuff
    } else {
        // keep doing some stuff
    }
}
```

I used your "pseudo-code" syntax because I'm not sure what exactly do you want to achieve, actual JS test code you need help with in your question would be much easier to understand and answer properly.

Comment: this IS actual JS code.  see my comments above.  no worries, though; @Mathletics sorted it for me.